# Reading gmail attachment in my app

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, email-attachments

I am trying to read (first time - new to me) a gmail attachment (.gcsb extension) in my app. The intent filter looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:pathPattern="*.gcsb"></data>
    <data android:mimeType="application/*"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

and that appears to get the 'download' and 'preview' buttons to appear next to the attachment in gmail (without that filter, the buttons do not appear).

In the activity (onCreate() / onRestart()) I do:

```
....
Intent  intent = getIntent();

if (!Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    //  Deal with the file from gmail here
}

....
```

to check if it is gmail that has caused this to start the activity or not.

However intent.getAction() always resolves to android.intent.action.MAIN, so it never does anything. There is another intent filter in the activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

being for the app launch, but I don't understand why I never see the android.intent.action.VIEW from gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that the activity was set to be 'single instance' for various reasons. This means that whilst it is brought to the foreground again, it comes back with the intent it was originally started with, not the one created by gmail.

Removing the 'single instance' attribute allowed the correct intent to be used.